# Hadoop Streaming Memory Usage

Tags: java, memory, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm wondering where the memory is used in the following job:

- Hadoop Mapper/Reducer Heap Size: `-Xmx2G`
- Streaming API:

  - Mapper: `/bin/cat`
  - Reducer: `wc`
- Input File is a 350MByte file containg a *single* line full of `a`'s.

This is a simplified version of the real problem we've encountered.

Reading the file from the HDFS and constructing a `Text`-Object should not amount to more than 700MB Heap - assuming that `Text` does also use 16-Bit per Character - I'm not sure about that but I could imagine that `Text` only uses 8-Bit.

So there is these (worst-case) 700MB Line. The Line should fit at least 2x in the Heap but I'm getting always out of memory errors.

Is this a possible Bug in Hadoop (e.g. unaccary copies) or do I just don't understand some required memory intensive steps?

Would be really thankful for any further hints.

Answer (score 0):

The memory given to each child JVM running a task can be changed by setting the `mapred.child.java.opts` property. The default setting is 
**-Xmx200m**, which gives each task **200 MB** of memory.

When you are saying -

> Input File is a 350MByte file containg a single line full of a's.

I'm assuming you file has a single line of all a's with a single endline delimiter.

If that is taken up as a value in the map(key, value) function, I think, you might have memory issues, since, you task have can use only 200MB and you have a record in memory which is of 350MB.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that `mapred.child.java.opts` _is_ `-Xmx2048M` - so a task can use up to 2GB memory

Comment: @mt_: How much does you overall system have? And, how much is allocated to the tasktracker and datanode for that machine?

Comment: Each machine has 16GByte memory and is configured for 2 map tasks and 1 reduce task -> no more than 6GB should be used at any time.

Comment: `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` is 5GB - so DataNode and TaskTracker should have each 5GB Heap - this could be the culprit as the value is probably to high

Comment: This does not seem to have anything do to with the failing job. The task fails on machines with `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` set to either 2GB, 4GB, or 5GB. Does not matter much

Comment: @mt_: At this moment I can just suggest you to set mapred.child.java.opts to -Xmx1000m and set Hadoop_HEAPSIZE to 1000GB. Look what free -m has to say about amount of free memory in your systems. Make sure you don't have parallel jobs running. And then try again. The thing is when the map task ask for 350MB of memory, it should get it and in your case somehow it's not able to acquire that.